# Converting a float to int

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I'm have this assignment where you have to get an input of type float from the user which represents a value in dollars
for example

4.05

so I want to convert this float to an int such that it becomes in cents so the value of the int should be 405 , I need to do this in C, anyone can provide some help ?

Comment: *How* many cents is $4.05?

Comment: Sorry @dlev, my fault, I didn't noticed it and never knew about this. Just hope I deleted it in time.

Comment: @sidyll: if you posted a solution, yes, you did. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, here are some leading questions:

1. You need to change a number in dollars to cents. What mathematical operation would do that?
2. You need to convert the result of that mathematical operation to an integer. How can you convert a float to an integer? (Hint: casting)

Comment: Casting is going to get him off by a penny.  I suppose that's what the homework assignment is about.  (Hint: rounding)

Answer (score 0):

First result on google with "float to int c": http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html. Next time, please google it !

Comment: This truncates whats after the floating point -_- , thats exactly what I don't want to do

Comment: @aedes993 I think he assumed you know how to convert from dollars to cents before converting to int. Too high an assumption?

Comment: @aedes993 As this is homework no one's going to just answer it; you have to convert the dollars to cent first by simple maths and then cast it

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of incidental to your question but in case you should decide to go further with your programming career and want to code something that involves non-integer values of money, you're safest using some kind of [decimal floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) library to avoid precision errors.

This is for Python but explains the rationale for using proper decimal numbers with currencies:

http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

In this assignment you'll probably be fine without it but using it and/or bringing it up in class might win a few extra credit points with your teacher. ;)